# How to drag and drop multiple rows in jface table in java RCP?

Tags: swt, jface, rcp

Here , setIdList is list of student ids. I want to add these ids into table. 
The ids are set in dragSetData() method.
I am able to access the list of ids by dropping into table. But it is adding at last of table.
I want it to add this list in between any row selected by mouse pointer.
Drag code...

```
private void addDragSupport() 
{
    int operations = DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_MOVE;
    Transfer[] transferTypes = new Transfer[] { TextTransfer.getInstance() };
    viewer.addDragSupport(operations, transferTypes, new DragSourceListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void dragStart(DragSourceEvent event) {
            event.doit = false;
            if (null != myVariable) {
                if (myVariable instanceof StudentDetails) {
                    event.doit = true;
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
            event.data = setIdList;
        }

        @Override
        public void dragFinished(DragSourceEvent event) {

        }
    });
}
```

I tried below in drop code

```
IStructuredSelection structuredSelection = this.getStructuredSelection();
List<StudentDetails> studentDetailList = structuredSelection.toList();
```

But it is giving me the selected row. I want the pointer selected by mouse.

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you are using table viewer.

In drop handler :

1) Get the model object from TableViewer : `tableViewer.getInput()`

2) From `dropTarget` object find the object location where you want to add dropped object.
Then insert new object in the model at that location and refresh the `tableviewer`